# Local kibana AWS Signature v4

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

i'm trying to connect a custom kibana with the AWS elasticsearch service, AWS ES cluster uses api keys based authentication and requires a signed request, viewing the code i can see there is a module aws4 installed but i don't see how is it used to sign requests, i can't see no configuration related in kibana.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried making a local proxy? https://github.com/abutaha/aws-es-proxy